# Waiting in vb2008 / vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am a VB6 coder and I'm making the move to VB8 / VB.NET

I know how to wait in VB6, but my problem is that I don't know how to wait in VB8/VB.NET. I have a `TextBox` called `textbox2` that contains the number of seconds I want to wait.   I used to use `wait 60` in VB6, but of course VB2008 is different.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Waiting in a GUI application is a pretty big no-go. Use timers for deferred action.

Comment: @nick please take your time and try to read through the answers before you post again with the same problems. I had given you how to get the contents of your TextBox in my answer prior to you asking two other people how to do it. I gave three different possible answers to how to wait, mentioned that the first would hang, and instead you tried it anyway and reported that: surprise, it hangs. yet, the *rest* of my post, has two *other* options: waiting with While and using a small Sleep with Application.DoEvents, and using System.Timers.Timer. take your time. your answers are all there.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I thought there were so many conflicting answers and I thought the solution I use is simple and straightforward enough. 
Also, I wrote this when I switched from VB6 to .net, for the same reason as OP.

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal seconds As Long)
    Dim dtEndTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds)
    While DateTime.Now < dtEndTime
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx):

```
Thread.Sleep(60000)
```

---

Update, following comment:

To retrieve and convert the value of the text box use:

```
Dim sleepValue As Integer = Integer.Parse(textbox2.Text)
```

This will throw an exception if the value cannot be converted.

Comment: Yes but i want 60000  two be textbox2   how can i do that ??

Comment: @nick - I'd expect you could put 1 and 1 together yourself. Show some effort, please.

Comment: Implying that `(CInt)textbox2.Text` will compile

Answer (score 0):

[edit: I re-read the question and see it was specifically asking about a `TextBox` named `textbox2` so I've updated the answer to reflect that.]

Well, I think one answer would be to use:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Int32.Parse(textbox2.Text) * 1000);
```

if your text box contains the number of seconds to wait. However if you aren't in a background thread, this will hang your application up for the amount of time you are waiting.

You could also do something like:

```
Dim StartTime As DateTime
StartTime = DateTime.Now

While (DateTime.Now - StartTime) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Int32.Parse(textbox2.Text))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

which would not hang up the UI while you wait. (Also, you could use Convert.Int32(textbox2.Text) to convert the data in the textbox.)

Oh, and in certain cases, another way you can avoid the issues with the UI locking up would be do implement a timer callback instead. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx for some more detail.) To do this, you

- do whatever processing you need to do before the pause
- create a function that picks up processing where you left off
- create a timer that calls your function afterward

Code:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public MyTimer As System.Timers.Timer

    Public Sub OnWaitCompleted(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        MyTimer.Stop()
        MyTimer = Nothing
        DoSecondPartOfProcessing()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoFirstPartOfProcessing()
        ' do what you need to do before the wait

        MyTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(Int32.Parse(textbox2.Text))
        AddHandler MyTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnWaitCompleted

        MyTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSecondPartOfProcessing()
        ' do what you need to do after the wait
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: when you don't know the type of the parameter ahead of time, you can also use the `Convert` object, for instance, `Convert.ToInt32(txtMyTextBox.Text)` to do the conversion

Comment: if you need the code for `textbox2` specifically, it's `Int32.Parse(textbox2.Text)` or `Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text)`

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Int32.Parse(textbox2.Text) * 1000);

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Int32.Parse(textbox2.Text) * 1000);
makes my program freeze ( goes white )

Comment: yes, as I stated, that call by itself blocks all activity on the UI until it returns; ("However if you aren't in a background thread, this will hang your application up for the amount of time you are waiting.") that's why I gave the second method. (doing a loop that calls a much smaller Sleep, and then Application.DoEvents, until the number of seconds have elapsed .)

Answer (score 0):

Use this do that your UI does not hang.

```
For i = 1 to 300
 threading.thread.sleep(i * 1000)
 application.doevents
next
```

Comment: depending on how long the DoEvents call takes, this could take significantly longer than 300 seconds, though.

Comment: I want two wait for how ever many seconds there are in textbox2

Answer (score 0):

try to use a timer

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim interval As Integer = 0

    If Integer.TryParse(Me.TextBox2.Text, interval) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = interval
        Timer1.Start
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'your code here
End Sub
```

In the 'event of the timer ticks then implements the logic to invoke the method Timer.Stop (), but this depends on what you do.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why do you want it and and why you don't use threads, but this `sleep` function act similar `wait` in vb6:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("begin")
    Sleep(2000)
    MsgBox("end")
End Sub
```

Comment: Why pInvoke when there are built in functions in the BCL?

Comment: i want two wait for how ever many seconds there are in text box 2

Comment: replace Sleep(2000) by Sleep(int(textbox2.text))

Comment: this really is overkill; did you have an advantage in mind for this over just using the .NET framework method to do so? (e.g. `Thread.Sleep` in the `System.Threading` namespace)?

Comment: hey, i know how to use .NET methods, but look at the question, if he knew what is thread he wouldn't ask such question. I think it was easy to understand for him than thread.

Comment: well, but it's less efficient and not portable and it would be impossible to remember it off the top of your head. I mean, and beyond that, `Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` is going to be *much* harder to remember for someone inexperienced than `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` even if you were right that `Thread` was more difficult, are you saying that it's better to give someone new to VB.NET a non-standard, non-portable, not-so-great answer than to give them the right way to do it?

Comment: Sleep(int(textbox2.text))  makes my program frezze ( goes white )

Comment: @shelley, no I don't say it's better to give non-standard methods to new user, but sometimes user don't like to learn best solution, he wants easiest way, something he is familiar with. dunno, it's my opinion.

Comment: @nick it's better you explain more about your project, your given information is not enough, why you want to have sleep in your program?